# A weird phenomenon of return iterator When erasing a range of elements in a vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, iterator, erase

The source code is as the following. When erasing a range of elements in a vector, we can infer that the return iterator refers to the element 30. But in Visual Studio 2010 the return iterator is not dereferencable, why?

The error information is:
vector iterator not dereferencable.

```
vector <int> v1;
vector <int>::iterator iter;
v1.push_back( 10 );
v1.push_back( 20 );
v1.push_back( 30 );
v1.push_back( 40 );
v1.push_back( 50 ); 
iter = v1.erase( v1.begin( ), v1.begin( ) + 2 );
cout << *iter << endl;
```

[image: local variables in Visual Studio 2010]

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/v7UD5Z).

Comment: Bug in Visual Studio 2010!? https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/606046/std-vector-erase-function-bug

Comment: @WernerHenze After noticing that it worked on ideone, I decided to test in VS. Couldn't reproduce it in both VS2012, and VS2010.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius VS2010 RTM or VS2010 with SP? It was fixed in SP1 for VS2010. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2010/12/09/vs2010-sp1-beta-whats-in-it-for-c-developers/.

Comment: @WernerHenze That explains it. The version that have is suffixed by `SP1Rel`, which, I expect, means that I am running SP1, with the bug fixed.

Comment: Thanks all of you, especially  Werner Henze, the problem puzzled me for a long time. I feel great now. By the way, the version of my Visual Studio 2010 is 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel.